# SQL-Server 2008 R2 geoSpatial query error for Circular String

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, geospatial, spatial, spatial-query

SQL Spatial Features: SQL geometry Point, **Linestring** working well but the **Circular** string is not working. When i try to save the CircularString type data to my geometry datatype its throws the following error:

My statement:

```
DECLARE @g1 geometry = 'CIRCULARSTRING EMPTY';
```

> "A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined
>   routine or aggregate "geometry":  System.FormatException: 24114: The
>   label CIRCULARSTRING EMPTY in the input well-known text (WKT) is not
>   valid. Valid labels are POINT, LINESTRING, POLYGON, MULTIPOINT,
>   MULTILINESTRING, MULTIPOLYGON, or GEOMETRYCOLLECTION."

Is this due my SQL Version ( I Am Using SQL Server 2008 R2) or I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As far as I can tell from the docs, [CircularString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff929141.aspx) was only added for SQL Server 2012. The only other [instantiable curve](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb964711.aspx) appears to be [LineString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb895372.aspx) which, as the name suggests, encodes a sequence of line segments. So your best bet would be approximating the circle as a (possibly regular) polygon with a sufficient number of corners. If that is not acceptable, you might have to keep your current data structures in place, either exclusively or in addition to spatial data types to verify that a match there indeed matches the circle.

This answer was written purely from the docs, with no experience to support it.

Please see reference on [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25790372/insert-a-circle-into-geometry-data-type).

Comment: ah.i just visited the page you mentioned, there the marked answer was not correct. Although got the answer in the last response on the page where it says the CIRCULARSTRINGS are included to sql server 2012 first time. I am not sure if its the answer but i will check the query in the SQLServer2012.