# SQL Server 2008 R2 to create circle

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2008, reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 and I would like to use CIRCULARSTRING to draw a circle. I could use the POINT and STBuffer but then the circle is filled with a color, while I want the outline. Trying to use the CIRCULARSTRING  I get an error message:

> label CIRCULARSTRING(2 0, in the input well-known text (WKT) is not valid. Valid labels are

So I read that this is a feature in SQL Server 2012.

My questions:

1. Is there a way to draw the outline of a circle in SQL Server 2008 R2?
2. Can I update SQL Server 2008 R2 to include this feature?
3. If I upgrade to SQL Server 2012 will it be compatible with VS2008 SSRS?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL-Server 2008 R2 geoSpatial query error for Circular String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27033997/sql-server-2008-r2-geospatial-query-error-for-circular-string)

Answer (score 0):

This function is presented in SQL Server 2012 (see link below).

1. You can create custom function to calculate coordinates of point on the circle. It can be `TSQL` (not sure you can do it) or `clr` (sure this is better way).
2. No.
3. No.

See also [here](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/tip-of-the-day.aspx?tkey=453d0b08-1551-4e74-ad6b-3f1502f4b196&tkw=sql-server-2012-new-spatial-instantiable-data-types).

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27033997/sql-server-2008-r2-geospatial-query-error-for-circular-string).